# Print arbitrary hex characters in u-boot shell

Tags: u-boot

I'd like colorize my u-boot bootcmd so it prints a breathtaking error message. Normally I'd just use ANSI escape sequences such as below.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
printf '\x1b[31mERROR\33[0m'
```

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
print("\x1b[31mERROR\33[0m")
```

How can get equivalent behavior in u-boot? It seems u-boot will just remove the backslash such as below

```
# u-boot shell
echo \33[31m  # prints "33[31m"
echo \x1b[31m # prints "x1b[31m"
```

Answer (score 0):

On a bash console you can use CTRL-V to enter a control character verbatim. This is not supported by U-Boot yet. But I have submitted a patch to enable this, cf. https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/uboot/list/?series=152686.

U-Boot's echo command does not know '\x' escape sequences but copies an escape character verbatim to the console.

So this is what you can do:

Create a script test.txt with your echo commands which contains the escape sequences.

```
echo -e 'echo \e[33mError\e[37m\necho \e[32mWarning\e[37m' > test.txt
```

I show it below in hexadecimal format so it becomes obvious what is in the file:

```
00000000   65 63 68 6F  20 1B 5B 33  33 6D 45 72  echo .[33mEr
0000000C   72 6F 72 1B  5B 33 37 6D  0A 65 63 68  ror.[37m.ech
00000018   6F 20 1B 5B  33 32 6D 57  61 72 6E 69  o .[32mWarni
00000024   6E 67 1B 5B  33 37 6D 0A               ng.[37m.
```

Convert this to a U-Boot image

```
mkimage -T script -n 'test' -d test.txt test.scr
```

In U-Boot load the script. I did this using tFTP:

```
dhcp $script_addr_r test.scr
```

Now you can execute the script

```
source $script_addr_r
```

When U-Boot is build with CONFIG_DISTRO_DEFAULTS=y it will look for scripts boot.scr.uimg and boot.scr on your boot device. So this is probably where you want to integrate the escape sequences.